# What is the difference between these two multivariate randomness definitions

Tags: probability

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.

Defintion 1: In wikipedia, one multivariate random variable is defined as $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ where $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Definition 2: If we define a new probability space $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',P')$ where $\Omega'=\Omega \times \Omega  \times \Omega \times....$ and $P'(A)=P(A) \times P(A) \times ...., A \in \mathcal{F}'$, then the multivariate random variable $X$ can be defined as $X:\Omega' \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

What is the difference between these two definitions?

Comment: The second is not a definition. It is stated there that a probability space can be built such that $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ can be looked at as a multivariate random variable defined on it. It lacks to state what is meant by $\mathcal F'$.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. $\mathcal{F}'$ is an event.

Comment: Then you should use other notation. $\mathcal F'$ denotes here the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega^n$ and $P'$ is meant to be a probability measure on it. So it sends elements of $\mathcal F'$ (i.e. events) to $\mathbb R$. $P(A)$ is defined for $A\in\mathcal F'$, but $P'(\mathcal F)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Correction: in my former comment $P(A)$ must be replaced by $P'(A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the imprecision about the definition of the product field is fixed, the   second boils down to  a special case of the first, in which the components $X_i$ are independent.